# Publishing an App with <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" does not seem to work

Tags: android, screen, google-play

To make my App visible from the Play Store on my two 10 inch tablets I had to add the following lines in the manifest:

```
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true"
```

In other words, I could see my App in Google Play on my PC but NOT on my two tablets UNTIL I added the three lines above in the manifest!

Why is that?  Android Development doc does not say anything about the

```
    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
```

statement NOT being sufficient by itself...

Since I would like to know for my next publishing work, does anyone have more details on this?

Any info would be extremely useful for future publishing!

Answer (score 1):

The Android Developer documentation states that the default values for android:largeScreens and android:xlargeScreens should be explicitly stated as it differs in some versions (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)).

The docs do explicitly state that android:requiresSmallestWidthDp is not used by Google Play for filtering, hence it would not be sufficient by itself.  It says [here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) "Caution: The Android system does not pay attention to this attribute, so it does not affect how your application behaves at runtime. Instead, it is used to enable filtering for your application on services such as Google Play. However, Google Play currently does not support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should continue using the other size attributes if your application does not support small screens."

Since android:requiresSmallestWidthDp is neither used by the application itself or by Google Play for filtering, it is currently of no use for apps distributed via Google Play.

Comment: Thank you flightplanner for the clarification.  Very useful.

Comment: So could you please tell me how to set the attributes to make my appliction only visible to 10 inch devices .

Comment: One caveat... Amazon now uses this attribute as a filter.  We had to remove it from the manifest.